# Should I transfer ~/snap/ when upgrading Ubuntu versions?

Tags: snap

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system with a `~/snap/` folder.  From reading, I've picked up only that this folder "represents certain user data for my installed snaps," which doesn't really tell me a whole lot.

I'm preparing to move all of my files to a new laptop that I'll install Ubuntu 22.04 on.  I understand (correct me if I'm wrong) that I won't be able to transfer the snaps I have installed, so I'll have to re-install them on the 22.04 system.  Should I transfer the `~/snap/` folder to the new system?  Will its freshly-installed snaps have any use for the files in the 18.04 `~/snap/` folder?

Comment: does this reference answer you question? https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-snap-developers-guide-on-how-to-migrate-to-new-bases

Comment: @24601  It does not, but thank you for looking.  That article doesn't touch on the `~/snap/` directory or its usage at all.

Comment: You *could* transfer all the snaps manually, but doing so is generally a waste of effort. It's much simpler for most users to `sudo snap install ....` on the new system rather than learning how to manually assert and install snaps that will promptly overwrite themselves from the online repo anyway.

Answer (score 8):

The `~/snap/` directory is where your USER DATA for your snap-provided applications is stored.

Examples:

- In Firefox, that's where your profile, bookmarks, history, and cookies are stored.
- In Thunderbird, that's where your profile and your mail are kept.
- In Discord, that's where your profile and conversation cache are kept.

If you want your user data, copy the directory.

If you want to start fresh, don't copy the directory.